# nested subquery can't related with main query

Tags: mysql

problem

in users.user_id in subquery it's unknown
and it's defined in main query no related between them

task is :

find user2 friends + mutual count with  user1

mysql to find user2 Friends and get mutual_count with user1 ( with every user2 friend)

Table users

```
user_id |   username
------------------
1       |   user1
2       |   user2
3       |   user3
4       |   user4
5       |   user5
```

table friends

```
user_one_id |   user_two_id
------------------------
1           |   2
1           |   4
2           |   3
2           |   4
3           |   1
5           |   2
```

Expected output           //( user2 friends : check result user_id with user1 to get mutual count)

```
user_id | mutual_count
------------------------
1       |   2             // user1 and user1 mutual users(user2,user3,user4)
3       |   1             // user3 and user1 mutual users(user2)
4       |   1             // user4 and user1 mutual users(user2)
5       |   0             // user5 and user1 -> No mutual users
```

mysql statement

```
SELECT  users.user_id,

(SELECT count(a.friendID) FROM
    (   SELECT user_two_id friendID FROM friends  WHERE user_one_id = users.user_id
        UNION 
        SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = users.user_id
    ) AS a 
    JOIN  
    (   SELECT user_two_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_one_id = 1
        UNION 
        SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = 1
    ) AS b 
    ON  a.friendID = b.friendID
) as mutual_count
FROM friends LEFT JOIN  users    
ON friends.user_one_id = users.user_id or  friends.user_two_id = users.user_id  
WHERE (friends.user_one_id = 2 OR friends.user_two_id = 2)   AND users.user_id != 2
```

Error I get
Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause'
problem subquery to get mutual_count canot know users.user_id

any help appreciated

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without UNION or subqueries like this :

```
SELECT
u.user_id,
IF(u.user_id = f.user_one_id, f.user_two_id, f.user_one_id) as friend_id,
COUNT(f2.user_one_id) + IF(f.user_one_id = 1 OR f.user_two_id = 1, 1, 0) as mutual_count
FROM users u
JOIN friends f ON f.user_one_id = u.user_id OR f.user_two_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN friends f2 ON 
(f2.user_one_id = 1 OR f2.user_two_id = 1)
AND (
  (f2.user_one_id = f.user_one_id OR f2.user_two_id = f.user_two_id) 
  OR (f2.user_one_id = f.user_two_id OR f2.user_two_id = f.user_one_id)
) 
AND f2.user_one_id != 2 AND f2.user_two_id != 2
WHERE u.user_id = 2  
GROUP BY friend_id
```

SQL Fiddle to test it out : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/701414/29

Comment: very thanks for you but still something error the first output record must be mutual_acount 3 not 2  ,   user1 and user1 mutual users(user2,user3,user4)

Comment: all record increased one  but only first record must be increased ex last record 5 -> 0  (true) but  on the new query  5->1  (wrong)

Comment: Doesn't exactly inspire confidence

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. @Strawberry I'm open to suggestions

Comment: My suggestion is wait until the op asks a better question